# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function calling a function on change form input

Tags: javascript, onchange

I get that error on this:

This function is inside jscript.js source in  section of index.php

```
function upd(ctd, ID, pr){      
    //$('#sub'+ ID).val() = ctd * pr;
    document.getElementById('sub'+ ID).value = ctd * pr;
}
```

I have a form built dinamically. This is a sample of one of some inputs, ID=4

This html is inside a div loaded from ajax

```
150 times 
<input name="ct4" id="c4" type="text" value="10" onchange="upd(this.value,4,150);" />
=<span id="sub4">1500</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XcYTc/247/

Comment: try document.getElementById('sub'+ ID).innerHTML instead

Comment: Also added "return": onchange="return ups(this....)

Comment: It is a not elegant working solution onchange="document.getElementById('sub'+ 4).innerHTML = this.value * 150";

Answer (score 0):

`span` element doesnot have value attribute, change to:

```
document.getElementById('sub'+ ID).innerHTML = ctd * pr;
```

See: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcYTc/248/)

Comment: In real life it does not work (same as fiddle onLoad framework). I load the function in the <head> section.